# When is the callback function of avio_alloc_context() triggered as the official ffmpeg documents?

Tags: ffmpeg

According to the official FFmpeg documents (such as the two links below), the fifth parameter of avio_alloc_context() function is the callback function. How can this callback function be triggered?

I don't understand the official documents very well.

```
AVIOContext* avio_alloc_context(unsigned char * buffer,
    int     buffer_size,
    int     write_flag,
    void *  opaque,
    int(*)(void *opaque, uint8_t *buf, int buf_size)     read_packet,
    int(*)(void *opaque, uint8_t *buf, int buf_size)     write_packet,
    int64_t(*)(void *opaque, int64_t offset, int whence) seek
)
```

Function link: [function link](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.1/avio_8h.html#a853f5149136a27ffba3207d8520172a5)

Code link：[code link](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.1/avio_reading_8c-example.html#a20)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***read_packet*** is called in ***avformat_open_input***().